# How to get 4 random images out of array of 6 images in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem. I need to get 4 random images out of array of 6 elements but I don't know how to do it. Images should repeat.

```
let array = ["../media/pawn.png", "../media/rook.png", "../media/knight.png", "../media/bishop.png", "../media/queen.png", "../media/king.png"];
shuffleArray(array);

array.forEach(function(image) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = image;
    img.height = "45";
    img.width = "50";
    document.getElementById("random").appendChild(img);
});

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: images should or shouldn't repeat ?

Comment: they should repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array = ["../media/pawn.png", "../media/rook.png", "../media/knight.png", "../media/bishop.png", "../media/queen.png", "../media/king.png"];

const images = Array(4).fill(0).map(() => array[~~(Math.random() * array.length)]);

console.log(images);
```

Comment: how can I display it on the screen 4 times in the div with id = random , instead of console?

Comment: Just like you did but instead of looping array loop the images array

Answer (score 1):

If image should repeat you can use simple random like that:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  console.log(array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)]);
}
```

As you can see log can show you same image (in my example just a number).

Comment: I tried to show it on screen but it doesn't work, idk if I can do it this way for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("random").appendChild((array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)]));
}

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a small loop

```js
let images = ["../media/pawn.png", "../media/rook.png", "../media/knight.png", "../media/bishop.png", "../media/queen.png", "../media/king.png"];

function shuffleImages () {
  let temp = []
  while (temp.length < 4) {
    temp.push(images[Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length - 1) + 1)])
  }
  return temp;
}

let array = shuffleImages()

console.log(array)

array.forEach(function(image) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = image;
    img.height = "45";
    img.width = "50";
    document.getElementById("random").appendChild(img);
});
```

```html
<div id="random"></div>
```